# Replace and push still don't work on same pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I have a simple inbox page that opens user messages. The trouble is that when a user clicks a message from the inbox from the inbox page...nothing happens.
I understand why this is the case for push but for replace it seems like a bug.

Attempting as so:

```
this.props.history.replace({
              pathname: "/inbox",
              state: { chatID: targetID }
            });
```

Comment: Here's the usage from react-router docs `replace(path, [state]) - (function) Replaces the current entry on the history stack` So you may try this or some other combination: `this.props.history.replace("/inbox", { chatID: targetID });`

Comment: @Rikin thanks but that has the same behavoir

Comment: fixed. Had to do with me not checking for the change in shouldComponentUpdate